# Difference, when observable variable is updated inside action method and plain function in mobx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am using **MBOX** for state management in **ReactJS**.

I sometime update observable variable inside some function, than also it re-render the react component and sometime i use `@action` method to update the observable variable.

So what it is the difference between the two scenarios and what effect it will have on rendering?

Answer (score 1):

An `action` is also a `transaction`, which means that any value that is derived from the observables you change in the action will be recalculated after the `action` is finished. If you don't wrap the function in an `action`, derived values might be calculated multiple times.

**Example - Recalculation after action ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/zuzasisama/1/edit?js,console,output))**

```
@observer
class App extends Component {
  @observable x = 'a';
  @observable y = 'b';
  @computed get z() {
    console.log('computing z...');
    return `${this.x} ${this.y}`;
  }

  onClick = action(() => {
    this.x = 'c';
    this.y = 'd';
  });

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.onClick}> {this.z} </div>;
  }
}
```

**Example - Recalculation straight away ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wisihasibu/1/edit?js,console,output))**

```
@observer
class App extends Component {
  @observable x = 'a';
  @observable y = 'b';
  @computed get z() {
    console.log('computing z...');
    return `${this.x} ${this.y}`;
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.x = 'c';
    this.y = 'd';
  };

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.onClick}> {this.z} </div>;
  }
}
```